# Running board above side walls in the basement

Tags: electrical, basement

My question is similar to [running board question here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201259/what-is-a-running-board-for-attaching-nm-cables-perpenticular-to-floor-joists) and I understand most of it but curious if those answers would apply if I need to run wires in the unfinished part above side wall in the finished basement. This unfinished part is hidden from view (accessible) due to suspended/drop ceiling.

See pictures for more info.

[image: Blue 1x4x8 furring strip, yellow 12g romex]

Comment: You're not attaching to the underside of joists. You appear to be attaching to the vertical side of studs.

Comment: Do you have some reason not to drill holes in the center of the studs?

Comment: That's right.. to the vertical side. One..its too many holes to drill  for one cable and would like to avoid making them weakers if code allows for the alternative.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use a running board if you want to.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-Furring-Strip-Board-687642/203461000

Comment: How about 1x4x8, above link,  as the running board?

Comment: That would be just fine.  Hard to tell detail from your pic, but couldn't you just run your cable in between the insulation and the "studs?"

Comment: @Huesmann you mean from behind the studs? So the cable goes behind the stud but comes back on the brown paper of the insulation and when reaches the next stud, it goes behind? Also, just found out that these vertical studs are notched to allow sewer pipe. Another reason not to drill holes.

Comment: @blackroses maybe.  What's behind the insulation?

Comment: Concrete foundation wall. That wall is just about the height of the insulation i.e. there some gap above concrete wall and the subfloor for the level above. So, can't secure cables there on the concrete wall. Also, the insulation you see are the batts between the foundation wall and the drywall. I do see some old/original cables running just above/along the concrete wall. Probably from before the basement was finished.